# If element has class add class to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if I'm doing this right. I have a menu that toggles between open and close. Now I want a button to show up if the menu `hasClass("open");`. and I would like to remove the class once the `class open` is gone.

Here is the HTML part;

```
<nav>
    <a class="closed"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Menu items</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="close-btn">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The HTML works, so this is not that important, the important part is that the elements are: `nav`, `a`, `closed`.

Now for the jQuery part;

```
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    if ($("nav a").hasClass("open")) {
        $(".close-btn").addClass('show-me-the-button');
    } else {
        $(".close-btn").removeClass('show-me-the-button');
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work. I've searched stackoverflow but all gave me this code... not sure why it isn't working. I get no script errors... any help?

Comment: You need to run your code within the event handler that toggle the `open`/`close` class on the menu

Comment: Your HTML does not have an element with the class `.close-btn`.

Comment: Might need more info here so please edit.
Are you trying to open and close by clicking on an item, or only on page load?
Or are you trying to "detect" when it changes.  If that's the case, you will need to create a different type of event.

Comment: Your jQuery code is executed exactly **once**  - on `document.ready`.

Comment: @connexo I edited my HTML code.

Comment: @AndrewIce At `detect` it should behave like an event listener...

Comment: It seems like you could use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) here. I kinda feel you're stacking classes for a simpler solution.

Comment: You should bind an event to the anchor tag, based on the event that triggers the class change. This can be tricky, since it's an anchor tag, you'll have to preventDefault().  But in the function that removes the "closed" class, just change the other element to an "open" class, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check classes only on initial page load. Where do you change `open` class? You should move this code in that place.

Answer (score 1):

User - *oryol* is correct

Try to put your code inside a handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    $('nav a').on('click', function(e) { // <----------- Click Handler (jQuery)

        // Use $(this) to access current clicked element
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(".close-btn").addClass('show-me-the-button');
        } else {
            $(".close-btn").removeClass('show-me-the-button');
        }

    })

});
```

> See more about [Click Handler in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Hope this helps!